# How to get the Phone Number of the device Using xcode

Tags: xcode6

I am writing an app using Xcode  in that i need to find the Phone number and auto populate in text box, so far I am able to find the device name ,please suggest me  away to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

As of 9th feb 2015, it is not possible using only public cocoa frameworks.

Comment: please  suggest me any alternatives way  to  achieve that